# Parameter passed to post controller is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This question is really similar to my last one but this has to do with passing multiple parameters.  My controller has two methods with the same name but one gets passed a nullable int to determine which action to take on post (I don't know if that's a good design decision).  Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult EventDetails(int? eventID)
{
    EventDetailsViewModel model = new EventDetailsViewModel();

     if (eventID != null)
     {
      model.afterPost = false;
      model.currentAttendance = getCountAttending(eventID);
      model.currentUser = getCurrentUserProfile(User.Identity.Name);
      model.eventDetails = getEventDetails(eventID);
      model.eventRestrictions = getEventRestrictions(eventID);
      model.usersAttending = getUsersAttending(eventID);
      return View(model);
     }
     else
     {
      return View();
     }
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EventDetails(int? eventID, int? action)
 {
     EventDetailsViewModel model = new EventDetailsViewModel();

     if (eventID != null)
     {
      model.afterPost = true;
      model.currentAttendance = getCountAttending(eventID);
      model.currentUser = getCurrentUserProfile(User.Identity.Name);
      model.eventDetails = getEventDetails(eventID);
      model.eventDetails["ActionID"] = action.ToString();
      model.eventRestrictions = getEventRestrictions(eventID);
      model.usersAttending = getUsersAttending(eventID);
      return View(model);
     }
     else
     {
      return View();
     }
 }
```

the view is huge but I'll post the relevant piece:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
 if (!Model.eventDetails["Event_Owned"].Equals("true"))
 {
     <div class="joinEventButton">
      @if(Model.eventDetails["Event_Current"].Equals("true"))
      {
          <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("EventDetails", "Event", new{eventID = Int32.Parse(Model.eventDetails["EventID"]), action = Int32.Parse(Model.eventDetails["CODE_RequestInvitation"])})">
           <input type="submit" value="Request Invitation" class="submitButton submitButton-green"/>
          </form>
      }
      else
      {
          <button class="disabledButton disabledButton-grey">Request Invitation</button>
      }
     </div>
 }
```

and just for good measure, my routes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

So the idea is that based on authentication and whether they own a specific event they are looking at, they will have different buttons show on the screen. This certain one is for when they want to join an event they can push a button to request an invitation. The controller knows this because of the int value being passed back as CODE_RequestInvitation.  The action being returned is always null. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Try put eventID in a hidden field in your form, and it might get sent up then.

Comment: Inspect the html. What is the value of the forms `action` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is the use of the parameter name `action` (which is conflicting with the `action` attribute). Change it to another name and it will work. Inspect he html of the `<form>` element before and after the change.

You code for generating the form is awful and the use of `Int32.Parse()` is pointless.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EventDetails", "Event", { eventID = Model.eventDetails["EventID"], actionID = Model.eventDetails["CODE_RequestInvitation"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Request Invitation" class="submitButton submitButton-green"/>
}
```

and post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EventDetails(int? eventID, int? actionID)
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Weird intricacies like that trip me up more than I dare say. Thank you so much for your response again (you helped me last time).

Comment: No problem, and please note the edit. Always use `Html.BeginForm` to generate your forms

Comment: On the other hand, you piked my curiosity with the bad form comment. I'm still just learning C# and MVC and think it would be great if you could tell me what are the awful pieces of it so I could fix them.

Comment: Just the fact your trying to manually generate the `<form>` element which is prone to typo errors. MVC has great html helpers for generating html and you should always use then (and always the strongly typed helpers for rendering controls). Apart from the fact that they work and mean writing less code, they validate other things, for example `BeginForm` will validate that the route matches your routes table and throw an error is not (something that would not be obvious with manually coding the tag).

Comment: As for `Int32.Parse()`, everything in html is strings so all you were doing was converting the value to an int which the browser then converted straight back to a string. Out of curiosity, why is property `eventDetails` a dictionary and not a model containing properties such as `eventID`?

Comment: I made eventDetails a dictionary so I could access specific elements of the information at specific places. Looking back it seems like doing three things when you only needed to do one. Thanks for the tip.

I only did the form that way because I'm not posting back any information, I just need it to go back to the [HttpPost] function and I didn't know how else to do it.

Comment: `Html.BeginForm`, like most of the helpers, allow you do do pretty much anything, including in this case adding route values and html attributes [Refer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). One more minor item, you do not have a specific route for the GET method of `EventDetails` so links will always be `/Event/EventDetails?eventID=1` rather that the generally preferred `/Event/EventDetails/1` so you should consider ading a specifif route with `url: "Event/EventDetails/{eventID}",`